# Selecting only ngrams based on the first word in rstudio

Tags: r, nlp, n-gram

I'm currently working on a nlp-project. As a training data set I'm using the Bible. You can easily create a random corpus with, if you want to try it yourself:

```
rcorpus(nwords = 50, alphabet = letters, minwordlen = 1, maxwordlen = 6)
```

After processing the text file, I'm dividing the corpus into n-grams with ngram-package

```
library(ngram)
# this is a preprocessed Corpus I have created earlier

bible_corpus<- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/XYZ/XYZ/"))
```

Now I'm processing the corpus with a function, I have set up earlier.

```
corpus_sentences <- Text_To_Clean_Sentences(paste(bible_corpus, collapse=" "))
```

Next step is to make a function for splitting our corpus into ngram

```
# function for getting n-grams
Get_Ngrams <- function(sentence_splits, ngram_size=2) {
ngrams <- c()
for (sentence in sentence_splits) {
sentence <- Trim(sentence)
if ((nchar(sentence) > 0) && (sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", sentence), length) >= 
ngram_size)) {
    ngs <- ngram(sentence , n=ngram_size)
    ngrams <- c(ngrams, get.ngrams(ngs))
     }
}
 return (ngrams)
}

# making n-grams based on Get_Ngrams
n2 <- Get_Ngrams(corpus_sentences, ngram_size=2)   
n3 <- Get_Ngrams(corpus_sentences, ngram_size=3)
n4 <- Get_Ngrams(corpus_sentences, ngram_size=4)
n5 <- Get_Ngrams(corpus_sentences, ngram_size=5)

# collect all n-grams
n_all <- c(n5,n4,n3,n2)
```

Time to enter a search term

```
# enter SEARCH Word
word <- 'good '

#
matches <- c()
for (sentence in n_all) {
    # find exact match with double backslash and escape
    if (grepl(paste0('\\<',word), sentence)) {
        print(sentence)
        matches <- c(matches, sentence)
    }
}

# find highest probability word
precision_match <- c()
for (a_match in matches) {
    # how many spaces in from of search word
    precision_match <- c(precision_match,nchar(strsplit(x = a_match, split = word)[[1]][[1]]))
}
```

The last step returns all ngrams, which contain our search word from line 29.

Now I want to remove all sentence which don't start with search word we have entered.

For example "precision_match" returns:

```
[1] search_word wordX wordY wordZ
[2] search_word wordY wordX wordZ
[3] wordY search_word wordX wordZ
[4] wordY wordX wordZ search_word
```

Of course I could manually select [1] und [2] since I can see that these two lines start with our search_word. But this isn't practical with a big number of matches. So how can I extract the n-grams starting with our search_word?

Comment: something like `precision_match[!grepl("^search_word", precision_match)]`?

Comment: Thanks! grepl was something that came to my mind.
But the function returns this:

     precision_match[!grepl("^word", precision_match)]

     [1] 15  0  9  4 10 14 19 15 11 16  0  6 14 18  0  4  4  9  0 13 19 13  0  9  
    4 13  6  0 10 17
     [31] 17 11 11  4  0 16  5  9 13  0  0 12 17  4  9 14  0  4 15  0  9  5  0 12 
    17  4 11 16  4 15
    [61]  5 11 17 17 17 12  0  5 17  0 23  4 19  0  9  4 16  6  0 10 19  6  0 10 
    10 14  0  6 11  0
     [91]  6 15 14  0 10  4 19  7 11  4 14  8  0  0  4  8  0 16  4 10 14  9 14  
    4  
    0  0  9 15  5  0

Comment: Can you add a small sample of precision_match with dput()

Comment: dput(precision_match) returns the following:

dput(precision_match)
c(15L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 14L, 19L, 15L, 11L, 16L, 0L, 6L, 14L, 
18L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 0L, 13L, 19L, 13L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 6L, 
0L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 0L, 16L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 
12L, 17L, 4L, 9L, 14L, 0L, 4L, 15L, 0L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 17L, 
4L, 11L, 16L, 4L, 15L, 5L, 11L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 12L, 0L, 5L, 17L, 
0L, 23L, 4L, 19L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 16L, 6L, 0L, 10L, 19L, 6L, 0L, 
10L, 10L, 14L, 0L, 6L, 11L, 0L, 6L, 15L, 14L, 0L, 10L, 4L, 19L)

Comment: Your `dput(precision_match)` output should consist of various strings according to your example `precision_match`. Not sure how you end up with the structure of the previous comment

Comment: If run precision_match through this function, I can get the best matched sentences, which is a string of characters ( a ngram with words). But View(precision_match) returns something similar to the dput-output from my previous post.

    best_matched_sentence4 <- sample(matches[precision_match == 
    max(precision_match)],size = 2)

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and don't know why you use the last part with the `precision_match...` 
It basically gives you the difference in positions of the search word from the beginning of the string. Your question however seems to be tackled at a step earlier (`matches`).

Try

```
set.seed(33)
test <- rcorpus(nwords = 50, alphabet = letters, minwordlen = 1, maxwordlen = 6)

Get_Ngrams <- function(sentence_splits, ngram_size=2) {
  ngrams <- c()
  for (sentence in sentence_splits) {
    sentence <- trimws(sentence)
    if ((nchar(sentence) > 0) && (sapply(gregexpr("\\W+", sentence), length) >= 
                              ngram_size)) {
      ngs <- ngram(sentence , n=ngram_size)
      ngrams <- c(ngrams, get.ngrams(ngs))
    }
  }
  return (ngrams)
}

ngram2 <- Get_Ngrams(test,2)
ngram3 <- Get_Ngrams(test,3)
n_all <- c(ngram2,ngram3)

word <- 'ghpbw'

matches <- c()
for (sentence in n_all) {
  # find exact match with double backslash and escape
  if (grepl(paste0('\\<',word), sentence)) {
    print(sentence)
    matches <- c(matches, sentence)
  }
}



matches[grepl(pattern = paste0("^",word), matches)]
```

which results in the ngrams starting with the search word `ghpbw` `[1] "ghpbw zbaiou"       "ghpbw zbaiou ffrpj"` discarding `[1] "wil ghpbw"        "dxjv wil ghpbw"   "wil ghpbw zbaiou"`